# Filtering similar values from an array of strings

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

If I have an array:

`["one", "two", "three", "thee", "four", "fowr"]`

And a function that compares strings for likelihood of matching:

`stringCompare('testing', 'testign')` outputs `0.7`

What is the best way to filter the array based on the `stringCompare()` function's result - say remove any value that scores 0.8 or above so that the resulting array would be:

`["one", "two", "three", "four"]`

Comment: Which elements are you comparing? Only adjacent ones? The basic idea is just map and then filter and then map again

Comment: 1. Do you consider using a library, or just plain javascript? 2. Do you want to compare the values just with the previous value, or with all values in the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also do this very easily with `lodash`:

```js
const array = ['one', 'two', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'three', 'two'];

const isSimilar = (s1, s2) => s1 == s2; // Switch this for your stringCompare function

const result = _.uniqWith(array, isSimilar);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `reduce`, `forEach` with combination of your `stringCompare` function (comments inline)

```js
var stringCompare = (str1, str2) => Number(str1 == str2); //assume for the purpose of this function

//fn to get duplicate values of a particular value in an array
var getDups = (s, i, arr) => arr.slice(i + 1).filter((it, ind) => stringCompare(s, it) > 0.8);
//fn to remove duplicate values from array
var removeDups = (arr, dupArr) => dupArr.forEach(s => arr.splice(arr.indexOf(s), 1));
var arr = ["one", "two", "three", "three", "four", "four"];

var output = arr.reduce( (acc, c, i, arr) => 
     (removeDups(acc, getDups(c, i, arr)), acc), //remove duplicates from accumulator
     arr);//initialize with input arr

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `filter()` method and inside you could take part of previous elements in array and check using `every()` method if every element is `<= 08` similar to current element in filter loop.

```js
const arr = ["one", "two", "three", "thee", "four", "fowr"]

function compare(a, b) {
  let found = 0;
  a.split('').forEach(e => b.includes(e) && found++);
  return found / a.length <= 0.8;
}
const result = arr.filter(function(a, i) {
  const prev = arr.slice(0, i);
  return prev.every(b => compare(a, b))
})

console.log(result)
```